# Blender Render Problem

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm making an animation and my problem is that as soon as an object is a little further away from the camera, it immediately disappears. Is there a setting for this? The object should still be visible.

Comment: check the Clipping values in the Camera panel > Lens > Clip Start and End

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)